# Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, next.js

My Next.js React app throws an error related to webpack. There is an error that I'm getting in development mode, however, in production build, everything works just fine. I've googled a lot a have no idea whats wrong I don't use any custom webpack configs, the only thing that i have in next.config.js is

```
module.exports = withImages({
    webpack(config, options){
        return config
    }
})
```

````
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Call Stack
__webpack_require__
file:///home/user/polenta/ploenta.com.ua/polenta/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (873:31)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (151:20)
eval
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/noop.js (58:41)
Object../node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/noop.js
file:///home/user/polenta/ploenta.com.ua/polenta/.next/static/chunks/0.js (11:1)
__webpack_require__
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (873:31)
fn
file:///home/user/polenta/ploenta.com.ua/polenta/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (151:20)
fn.t
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (195:35)
```
````

Comment: At what point are you getting the error? When you build the app or when trying to access it in the browser? Try deleting your `.next` folder and building again.

Comment: @juliomalves When I start a development server and trying to access it in the browser. 
But when I run yarn build & yarn start there is no error